EF Core 8 : Expression in the SQL tree does not have a type mapping assigned
The following query was working fine in EF Core 7:
string[] values = new[] {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

var query = (from item in _context.items
             let value = item.value != null ? values[item.value] : ""
             select new {item.id, value}).ToList();

However, after upgrading to EF Core 8, the following exception is thrown:

System.InvalidOperationException: Expression '' in the SQL tree does not have a type mapping assigned.

I checked the breaking changes documentation and I am running SQL Server 2022 with compatibility level set for my database to 160.
What am I missing here?

Note: this question was edited following the discussions with community members. I had to simplify the code in order to report the issue and I missed the key part which was the ternary operator: let value = item.value != null ? values[item.value] : "" and was using let value = values[item.value] instead.


What am I missing here?

Well, it looks like regression. EF Core 8 should not process this projections as SQL, but it does.
Detection what should be processed on the client side and what is translatable is fragile algorithms, so better to help EF Core to do it right:
string[] values = new[] {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

var query = (from item in _context.items
                .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.value }).ToList() // select only needed fields
             let value = values[item.value]
             select new {item.id, value}).ToList();

But create issue about that in EF Core repository, so they can create regression test and fix this regression.
Also you can try simplify query, by removing let operator, which is additional Select
var query = (from item in _context.items
             select new {item.id, value = values[item.value]}).ToList();


Wouldn't using ToList() in .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.value }).ToList() mean retrieving all the records in the items table? Can you please explain why using let value = values[item.value] causes an additional Select? Shouldn't this be evaluated in the same way only when .ToList() is called?

Yes, it retrieving all records (as in your original query), you can replace it with AsEnumerable(). let is syntax sugar it is equivalent to query.Select(x => { x, value = values[x.value]}).Select(x => new {x.x.id, x.value}).ToList())

I am leaving the query as IQueryable and doing the filtering, pagination and projection at the very end. What you suggested would be getting the required records and then replace the value according to the values array at client side. It is a valid approach but I was hoping to achieve this in one query just like it was in EF Core 7. I opened an issue at the EF Core repo to see if anything can be done.

You can do pagination at the start as workaround.

I cannot reproduce your issue with 8.0.0, same as the EF Core  team member responded to the issue you've opened in their repo. Something is wrong or missing in your scenario, and the "workaround" you've provided as a solution is weird / makes no sense. Most probably your values is not passed as string[], but something else which resolves to element type object.

@IvanStoev  I had to simplify the actual code which I am having trouble with in order to report the issue and looks like I missed out the problematic part. When declaring the value variable I am doing a null check to provide a default value when the value is null something similar to the following: let value = value != null ? values[item.value] : "default value". Are you able to reproduce the issue with this change?

@Damascus Now I do. Definitely bug, please make sure you provide the same info in EF Core repo issue you have opened. Happens in 8.0.4 as well (latest).

Converting the value retrieved from the values array to a string solved the issue and the SQL was translated properly:
string[] values = new[] {"one", "two", "three", "four"};

var query = (from item in _context.items
             let value = item.value != null ? values[item.value].ToString() : ""
             select new {item.id, value}).ToList();

I am not sure, it seems that EF Core -at the moment- isn't able to figure out the type of the values array during translation?
Edit: the version I am using of EF Core at the moment is 8.0.0
